# Python: Set the values of a dataframe equal to those of another one, given equality between several columns of the two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following two dataframes:

```
df1:
Column1         Column2   Column3  Column4  Column5
2007-10-31      1M        1        1Y       NaN
2007-10-31      1M        2        2Y       NaN
2007-10-31      1M        3        3Y       NaN
2008-03-14      3M        3        3Y       NaN
2008-03-14      3M        4        4Y       0.00873205
2008-03-14      3M        5        5Y       NaN
2008-03-14      3M        6        7Y       0.0111537
```

```
df2:
Column1         Column2  Column3     Column4
2007-10-31      1M       1Y          0.0188979
2007-10-31      1M       2Y          0.0196142
2007-10-31      1M       3Y          0.0181974
2007-10-31      3M       1Y          0.0188979
2007-10-31      3M       2Y          0.0196142
2007-10-31      3M       3Y          0.0181974
```

I would like `df1.Column5` to be set equal to `df2.Column4` under the conditions that `df1.Column1 = df2.Column1` and `df1.Column2 = df2.Column2` and `df1.Column4 = df2.Column3` (of course with the rest of the values of `df1.Column5` that do not satisfy the conditions, to remain untouched). I have already tried to use the `merge` function but it doesn't give exactly the desired result, which is:

```
Column1         Column2   Column3  Column4  Column5
2007-10-31      1M        1        1Y       0.0188979
2007-10-31      1M        2        2Y       0.0196142
2007-10-31      1M        3        3Y       0.0181974
2008-03-14      3M        3        3Y       NaN
2008-03-14      3M        4        4Y       0.00873205
2008-03-14      3M        5        5Y       NaN
2008-03-14      3M        6        7Y       0.0111537
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code that you tried so far? Porbably it will work with little changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
res = df.merge(df1, left_on=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column4'],
                     right_on=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'],
               how='left', suffixes=('', '_y'))

res['Column5'] = res['Column5'].combine_first(res['Column4_y'])
res = res[df.columns]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
      Column1 Column2  Column3 Column4   Column5
0  2007-10-31      1M        1      1Y  0.018898
1  2007-10-31      1M        2      2Y  0.019614
2  2007-10-31      1M        3      3Y  0.018197
3  2008-03-14      3M        3      3Y       NaN
4  2008-03-14      3M        4      4Y  0.008732
5  2008-03-14      3M        5      5Y       NaN
6  2008-03-14      3M        6      7Y  0.011154
```

The key here is to use *combine_first*, from the documentation:

> Update null elements with value in the same location in other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder, conditionally to the broad use of pandas dataframes, why this kind of operation can't be simplified?